# Open External Link in Anchor Tag

Tags: html, css, code-snippets

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="default"><a href="#homepage">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#research">Research</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Publications</a></li>        
    <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like the link

```
<li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
```

to redirect to another external page. So I changed the code like this:

```
<li><a href="http://www.blogname.com/">Blog</a></li>
```

But the whole page messed up and got crazy on me. Is there a way I can make this work somehow?

Comment: What is your problem? explain it..

Comment: Can you please explain it clearly

Comment: @mr-green, I'm not certain why it's not working though but what I realize is if I use #blog it works perfectly but when I try to use external URL, all the links on the page stop responding. 

For this template: http://www.dahndesigns.net/themeforest/summit/

All the top links are anchor tags. If I change any of them to an  external page, all the links stop responding.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer. I was also getting this problem but then I researched and found that we have to use a protocol like `https://` and `http://`  before we open an external link. you can see my research.

```html
<li><a href="https://msnetwork-1.web.app">v</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

i have set working example i think in your html you forget to close any tag

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="default"><a href="#homepage">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#research">Research</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Publications</a></li>        
    <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.blogname.com/">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/FvuHX/)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this also and it works as standalone but when I use it in the main code it doesn't respond.